# upgraded my unity from 2018.4.0 to 2019.3.7, I cannot build an apk now

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, unity-game-engine, build

[image: Android Modules]I cannot build an apk, probably libraries are not resolved. Following are the errors:
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.7f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.7f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
D8: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.ChecksumException

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.

  > com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
]
stdout[

> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:checkReleaseManifest
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseManifest
>
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
>   /Users/eapple/Documents/LeroBackups/LERO/Temp/gradleOut/unityLibrary/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:3:3-29:17 Warning:
>       application@android:allowBackup was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:3 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>
> Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
>   Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResValues
>   Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResources
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
>   /Users/eapple/Documents/LeroBackups/LERO/Temp/gradleOut/launcher/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
>       activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseResources
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
>   Task :launcher:signingConfigWriterRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseRFile
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:generateReleaseRFile
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseSources
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:javaPreCompileRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:bundleLibCompileRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:bundleLibCompileRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:bundleLibResRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:bundleLibResRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
>   Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
>   Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
>   Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
>   Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :launcher:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :launcher:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED
>   R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
>   https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
>   disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
>   Current version is: 1.4.77 (build b74371231cb896b02f83285efb055b7c00ff64d8 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-eqqf)).

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
84 actionable tasks: 44 executed, 40 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <88091cc0f6184c3ca77702906799aea5>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:340)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you change the Unity version you have to redownload and install the corresponding Android module from Unity Hub

edit if you dont see android build support under the version of unity you are using you will have to download the android module again from unity hub for the version of unity you are using

[image]

check for robot icon in unity hub if not click three dots and add module -> android -> click the boxes under 'android build support' in the collapsable menu
[image]

Comment: I did install androiod modules from unity hub. still same errors.

Comment: Did you change unity version after you downloaded them? if so you have to download the corresponding android modules again

Comment: I updated my answer with some more things for you to try

Comment: I added screenshot in my question

Comment: what unity version is your project set to? can you screen shot your project?

Comment: My project was set to 2018.4.0 and now I upgraded it to 2019.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

look in `Edit >> Preferences >> External Tool` what JDK, SDK and NDK you are using (if it's the developer kits installed with unity).

The Unity is trying to compilate an apk with gradle 6.0

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

but it's using gradle 5.1

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.7f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.7f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Try look in Unity HUB if has any update for android module (in my case, I need to install that)
[image]

Comment: there is no update on unity hub and I also tried with gradle 6.0, not working

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are affected by this issue which was happening with the older Hub releases: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-editor-shows-that-the-android-ndk-is-not-recommended-even-though-it-is-installed-from-the-hub

You should have your Hub at version 2.3.1 now.